# Replicating the behaviour of SketchUp's plugin "Soap Skin Bubble" in Blender

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I wish to use Blender to replicate the way one of SketchUp plugins work, as closely as possible.

I exactly mean the part described in 1:22-1:48 of this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQGTGAJ7p_w

He creates a complex outline, then fills it with mesh and "inflates" the mesh. The topology doesn't have to be in quads, nor it has to be very regular. I don't care much about topology, just about the silhouette.
Is this possible to do in Blender?

I first took a look at some tutorials covering balloon cloth simulation, but it won't work because the boundary edges must not be moved in my case. They have to stay in place. This is crucial.

I appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: you could do it with Proportional Editing (editable in the Operator box), or with the Cast modifier for example, maybe there's an easier way...

Comment: But none of this method will guarantee that the outline edges stay intact. They will be moved too. I have one thought, though. SketchUp has a cloth toolbox too. You can "pin" chosen vertices, so they always stay unmoved. If in Blender it's possible too, I could "pin" the boundary loop, add a force field and blow some wind from the bottom. Does this make any sense?

Comment: is it supposed to be animated? with a good setting you can make that it won't affect the outline

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be animated. I should have mentioned that. Just want to achieve the final result.

Comment: What tool/ setting can I use to pin/ lock chosen vertices, so they are not affected by physics/ cloth simulation? Can I make it that way?

Comment: seems doable with cloth but have you tried with Proportional Editing or Cast modifier? What is the problem with these methods?

Comment: I just can't imagine how I would use any of these methods to achieve this result. Firstly, I have to somehow interpolate the single face to get some density mesh. I used Boundary Aligned Remesh addon for that. See the screenshot, it's in the left (in the right I just used subvivision - obviously crappy result). Cast modifier rounds 3D meshes. My mesh is 2D - it has zero height. Proportional editing? Again, how would I protect the boundary loop? How would I achieve such smooth silhouette? Likely impossible.

Comment: yes, ok, because your shape is more complicated than an ovale  ;)  so yes, cloth may be the solution, or only keep some edges and try LoopTools > Loft? This is a solution, I'm not sure there's any quick tool but maybe someone will tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloth simulation can work very nicely as a modelling tool in Blender.

Some differences from the Sketchup add-on you refer to:

- Blender Cloth is more general, so there are more settings. They can be saved as presets, though, once you've got them sorted out.
- The Sketchup add-on assumes the boundary of the shape is pinned. In Blender, you have to pin vertices explicitly. Create a 'Pin' vertex group, allocate it with weight 1,  and declare it pinned in the 'Shape' panel of the Cloth settings. (Name the group whatever you like)

[image]

- Blender Cloth Pressure (one of the 'Physical Properties' panels)requires a a closed manifold mesh, otherwise it 'leaks' So, as you see, your shape has been extruded downwards, and the bottom face filled. The rim and base can be discarded after applying the Cloth modifier.
- I also added a 'Tension' vertex group to control the shape of inflation.. to give the inflated shape a thinner waist:

[image]

Unlike the add-on, the Blender simulation runs as an animation. This one stabilized in about 20 frames.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, cloth simulation worked very well! Actually I didn't even need to use pressure or vertex weights. I made a non-manifold mesh and just "inflated" it with timeline slider, controlling the "strength" of inflation with Vertex Mass or just converting the inflated cloth to mesh and scaling it in Z.

Comment: @michalpe Ahh.. I guess you were using gravity, then. Simpler. Different mechanism to Sketchup's, I think. A purpose-built simulator gives you a lot more options, at  the cost of simplicity.

Comment: I actually used the default settings. Wasn't even aware of the gravity setting :P But yeah, it was enough for me :) But thank you for your complex answer. I will use it in the future if I need more tailored solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible way via modifiers and helper objects.

Add a *[warp modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/warp.html#warp-modifier)* to your target object, as well as two empties. Place one of the empties at the world origin, and the second above in the direction you wish to move the influence.

[image]

[image]

The first empty is the beginning point (at the world origin), the second is the end and controls the movement of the modifier. (It is useful to add a subdivision surface modifier also to smooth things out here)

Adjust the location of the control empty and warp settings, and you should have a result similar to this:

[image]

---

To "pin" the object, you may add a plane to the world origin and hide it from view and render, and add a *[shrinkwrap modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html#shrinkwrap-modifier)* to the circle object. Add a vertex group at the perimiter of the circle to define the pin area and use the modifier in the shrinkwrap. This will allow you to use a larger radius in the warp modifier and keep the edges pinned.

[image]

[image]

The final modifier stack would like like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice method but I discovered that cloth will work better. Thank you anyway :)